# Windows shell to play (enqueue) all video files in correct order

Tags: windows, batch

I'm burning series on a DVD. I'd like to include *Play all* option to play them all. Of course, this should work for any player the system has installed.

What I'm trying to do is to invoke the very same action user invokes by selecting all video files and selecting `Open`.

This is what I have tried:

```
rem Start executes the default action for the given file
start ../*.mkv
```

Doesn't work:

[image: image description]

But it should really be possible. Once again, this is the task I want to automate:

[image: image description]

Any sane player will enqueue all the files and play the one you right-clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick 'n' dirty approach and see if it works for you (does for me but I haven't tested it on systems with different default players):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Get ProgID associated with AVIs
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKCR\.avi /ve ^| find "REG_SZ"') do set progID=%%a
REM Get open command for that ProgID
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query HKCR\%progID%\shell\open\command /ve ^| find "REG_SZ"') do set progNM=%%b
REM Now we should hopefully have "drive:\full\path\to\player.exe" "%1", so let's chop off the last 5 chars
set progNM=%progNM:~0,-5%
REM Expand wildcards and append filenames after program name
for %%a in (%1) do set progNM=!progNM! "%%~a"
REM Run the program with all the files and hope it won't result in N separate instances bogging down the system!
%progNM%
```

Save it as **Play.bat** for example and call it using `play *.mkv` or similar.

The code attempts to locate the program associated with AVIs, assumes that's the video player in use for all video formats, expands something like *.mkv to "File1.mkv File2.mkv ..." and passes them all to the program. Keep in mind that if there are too many files then the maximum command line length is bound to be exceeded (I think it's still [8192 chars](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx)), but hopefully in that case the program will still launch with as many complete file names as could fit.

Comment: Thanks! It's really cool, but it doesn't work... yet. One rather simple problem is that the `reg query` returns localised data. On my PC, `reg query HKCR\.avi /ve` returns this line among others: `(Výchozí)    REG_SZ    WMP11.AssocFile.AVI`. But the worse problem is that the first for loop doesn't take a single iteration (even fith fixed find command). That's something I don't know how to resolve. What does the `"tokens=3"` mean?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about localised strings. Instead of (Default) I edited the code to search for REG_SZ now, which should be the same regardless of language. Can you try it now? `for /?` will tell you about the tokens option. It basically returns the 3rd token (roughly whitespace separated string component) from the full string. If it still doesn't work, let me know the exact output of the two reg query commands on your system (remember to replace %progID% in the 2nd call with the actual ID returned by the 1st).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cmd file with just the filenames to be played (no 'start' command) i.e. **playlist.cmd**

```
episode01.mkv
episode02.mkv
episode03.mkv
episode04.mkv
```

and when you run this file it will open all the media files in whatever player is associated with the file type. Problem is, it starts to play all of the files one after another, without waiting for them to finish playing (which of course is not what you want - at least VLC does this for me).

Comment: Yes, this is not a solution. When you select and play files, windows executes `player.exe name1 name2 ...`. That's exactly what I need, but without knowing the player name

Comment: Windows Media Player can read a file list with extension **.m3u**. Simply list the files in the desired order in a text file and change the extension from .txt to .m3u. VLC and other apps recognize that format as well. **N.B.** If the files and .m3u playlist are not all in one folder, then files must be listed with *absolute path*, not practical for a DVD.